# property name for input or output

Tags: terminology

This is just a general terminology question.

We have an object which represents a "signal" which can be an input or output.  We are trying to think of a name for the property which indicates this.  The best we have come up with is "direction", but I think there must be a better term for the "in/out-ness" of a signal?

Answer (score 0):

How about: `IOSignal` (or whatever the variable name casing is in your language)?

Comment: hm, an okay suggestion but was hoping for an adjective ;)  thanks!